# Eclipse Neon - How to indent HTML 5 semantic elements like <main>, <article>?

Tags: eclipse, html, eclipse-formatter

I'm using Eclipse <strike>Neon</strike> Oxygen June 2017 with webtools so that I can work on a project using Tomcat and have SVN support as well. Eclipse doesn't like semantic HTML5 tags like main and article out of the box, it seems. I changed the validation settings so that it doesn't give me warnings on them, but I haven't found a way to change their indentation. Right now, main and div will be indented on the same level like so:

```
<main>
<div class="row">
```

Has anyone figured out how to fix this? It's quite annoying when the formatter puts them on the same level. Would I be able to use Tomcat, emmet, and SVN in Aptana Studio and just forget this mess?

Comment: HTML5 is a living standard. *Always* retry it with the latest release, which btw is not Neon. Can you also clarify what "Eclipse doesn't like semantic HTML5 tags like and out of the box, it seems" means?

Comment: I'm actually using Oxygen @nitind not sure why I said Neon. I put brackets around the tags so they couldn't be seen, but Eclipse says that main and article aren't valid tags, and after adding them to validation it still won't indent another level on these tags, as shown in the little excerpt above.